# When Importing typescript module into js, how to suppress typescript warnings?

Tags: reactjs, warnings, react-typescript

I am using the https://github.com/rouftom/react-mui-fileuploader module for file uploads.  My code is in javascript and this module is written in typescript.   Intellij however is complaining about the module and is outputting stuff like this:

```
Element FileUpload doesn't have required attribute bannerProps
Type boolean is not assignable to type PropTypes.Requireable<boolean>  Assigned type doesn't contain call signatures
```

Everything works, but I want to suppress the 20 lines of warning messages or fix it if possible.   However, I can't find any Intellij command to do that.   Is there a way to suppress all these warnings?